# How to trace what happens in DinkToPFD?

Tags: asp.net-core

My Asp.Net Core 2.1 app can generate two HTML reports. Each report has a button for outputting the report as a PDF file using DinkToPDF. The button calls a controller for that report that provides all the parameters that DinkToPDF needs and then generates the PDF. An essential parameter is the URL of the page to be converted, which is not the original HTML report but a lookalike from which javascript etc. has been removed.

The first report would output the login page instead of the report data until I put [AllowAnonymous] above the class name. Then it worked fine.

The second report used the files from the first report as a template. In all necessary places everything was renamed appropriately. But even though this page of course has [AllowAnonymous], it will only generate a PDF of the login page.

I can step through the controller code and watch the DinkToPDF params get their values. But when "convert" method of DinkToPDF is called, something goes wrong.

Is there a way to watch inside that method to see why it thinks it must authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

After I thought to look in the Output window, I saw that this was one of those "Qt: Could not initialize OLE" errors. I also found that the database context object being injected into my class was null. Evidently the context was being lost somehow. In the original report, that didn't matter because I had sidestepped EF Core and was accessing the database by old-style ADO-type calls.

Therefore, in the new report, I replaced all EF Core with ADO-type calls, and the problem went away. Just had to work out some routing.